# Tautology of $\mathcal{L}_X(J)=0$ and flow of $X$ consisting holomorphic transformation where $J$ is complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, lie-derivative

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold with complex structure $J$. Suppose $X$ is a real vector field over $M$.

$\mathcal{L}_XJ=0$ iff flow of $X$ consists of holomorphic transformation of $M$

The following is a dumb question. The reference is http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf

pg 14 Lemma 2.7.

Q: Why this is tautological here? I do not see this is obvious. The flow is made of 1 parameter group along some other real vector field.

Comment: A late comment 2 years later. I'm also studying the same material. I don't understand what " flow of $X$ consists of holomorphic transformation of $M$" means since the note doesn't give a definition. Does that mean flow of $X$ is holomorphic function on $M$?

Comment: @Andrews It follows from accepted answer that the small deformation preserves complex structure. And the vector field is the corresponding derivative. Hence it had better be holomorphic on each component if you treat it as complex vector field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general fact about flows and tensors that is essentially a generalization of the fact that a differentiable function is constant if and only its derivative is zero. Whether or not you label it as tautological is a matter of taste, I suppose.

The Lie derivative of a tensor field is typically defined by $$\mathcal L_X T = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \Phi_t^* T$$where $\Phi_t$ is the diffeomorphism given by flowing along $X$ for time $t$.

> **Proposition.** $\mathcal L_X T = 0$ if and only if $\Phi_t^* T = T$ for all $t$.

*Proof.* The "if" direction is immediate from the definition above. To get the other direction, we need to "integrate" $\mathcal L_X T = 0.$ Differentiating the flow group law $\Phi_t \Phi_s = \Phi_{s+t}$ with respect to $s$ at $s=0,$ we find that the derivative of $\Phi^*_t T$ at a general time is simply $$\frac{d}{dt} \Phi_t^* T = \Phi_t^* \mathcal L_X T;$$ so $\mathcal L_X T = 0$ in fact implies that $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t^* T = 0$ for all times. Thus $\Phi_t^* T$ is constant in $t,$ so it is always equal to $\Phi_0^*T = T.$$\;\square$

Since holomorphic transformations are defined exactly as diffeomorphisms $\phi$ satisfying $\phi^* J = 0,$ this specializes to answer your question.

Comment: Excuse me,sir. I've a question. In the reference above holomorphic transformations are defined such as "its differential commutes with the complex structures at each point: f∗ ◦ J1 = J2 ◦ f∗". Why this is equivalent to f∗J=J (I think there is a typo when you wrote "ϕ∗J=0)"